# How to access a Child Process' sockets in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, vlc, child-process

I am currently running into a very strange problem.

I am trying to start VLC using a NodeJS child process and then accessing it's Remote Control (RC) interface using socket. The problem occurs when connecting to this socket. I get an error, connection refused. The port is open and the application is allowed from the firewall.

The tricky part is, when I open VLC manually using this interface, and only try to connect on the socket, it works. I am assuming something in the spawned process makes things different causing the error somehow.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var file_dir = "V:\\TEST\\";
var files = ["Ika.mkv", "Nami.mkv", "Azu.mkv"];

var player = spawn("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", ['--intf="rc"', '--rc-host="localhost:3000"', '--fullscreen', file_dir + files[0]]);

var net = require('net');
var client = net.createConnection(3000, "localhost");

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected to VLC on port 3000');
    client.write("add " + file_dir + files[1] + "\n");
    client.write("enqueue " + file_dir + files[2] + "\n");

    client.write("help" + "\n");
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

I have tried this code on two machines, and I am running into the same problem.

Some questions you may ask:
**What operating system?** Windows 8.1

**Why do I need to use a socket?**
VLC doesn't have any interfaces that read and write from standard in or standard out. I have tried many different options and they simply do nothing.

**What am I trying to build?**
A Media Center with an web interface to it. I am using VLC as a media player.

**Can't you use the built in HTTP interface?**
It doesn't suit what I want to build. I want more control over managing my media.

---

Any and all help would be welcome. My thanks.

---

Comment: Could this be a timing issue where you need to wait for the spawned application to finish getting initialized before you try to connect to it?

Comment: I have just tried this, I started one instance with just the spawned process, the other with just a net connection and the second application errored out in the same way. ECONNREFUSED.

I didn't really think this was the issue, since I did always briefly saw VLC come up, then my application would throw the error and VLC would close as the app exited.

Comment: Just because you visually see something come up doesn't mean that it was ready for a connection in time.  If you really want to rule this out as a test, then put all the client connection code in a `setTimeout()` that waits 30 seconds before making the connection.

Comment: That still wasn't the issue, the app crashed 30 seconds in if I did this. Same reason, could not connect to the VLC process. So it doesn't seem like a timing thing. I am wondering if the child process even creates the socket.

Comment: It sounds like it isn't listening on the socket you think it is.  You can just run the program normally and then run `netstat -ab | more` while it is running in a Windows console window that is running at administrator privileges (so it can see all processes) and it will show you what processes have listening sockets.

Comment: Yeah it does not show up at all when it is launched from my NodeJS app. No application is listed under port 3000

Comment: Does it show a listening socket when vlc.exe is run other ways?

Comment: Yes, I have started the exact same process from command line and it shows up as a process.

Comment: Then, I would guess that your command line arguments are not being passed correctly when you start it as a child process.

Comment: Oh wow, I do seem to have found the error. I will answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out for some strange reason not all command line arguments get passed to the VLC instance.

I solved it by grouping together the instancing of the RC interface and the setting the RC mode to localhost:3000

This is the new line to spawn a process

```
var player = spawn("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", ['-I rc --rc-host=\"localhost:3000\"','--fullscreen', file_dir + files[0]]);
```

This works, only downfall is it also creates a RC console window, but I can live with it.

Thanks to @jfriend00 for helping solve the strange mystery.